# iframe displays "refused to connect" for Grafana

Tags: iframe, blazor, grafana

I am using grafana version 6.5.3 and I am trying to make a grafana dashboard be displayed in an iframe on a webpage in my blazor server app. The iframe is rendered but displays the following message "xxx.xxx.com refused to connect".

```
<iframe src="http://xxx.xxx.com/mygrafanacharts"
     frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

The Grafana server is configured with

```
allow_embedding = true
```

I have no clue if the Grafana server is not configured correctly or if there is some configuration that needs to be changed on my website.

Comment: HI. Any solution? Same problem here...

Comment: @AlexPoca Hi Alex, No we still have this issue, but it is not prioritized so I have not tried to solve it. I would be thrilled if you would post a solution if you find one.

Comment: I will. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem and was sure, I changed the
`allow_embedding = true`
setting, but when I wanted to confirm this and looked under http://[yourGrafanaServer]/admin/settings
I saw, that it was still `false`.

When I opened the grafana.ini, I realized, that I had forgotten to remove the `;` at the start of the line to uncomment the setting. After doing that, the iframe worked fine!
Maybe this was the issue here too.